# Creating radio buttons to delete text

Tags: android

This is the code I have for a "grocery list" app, which lets you type text and add it to your list. I want to add a radio button next to each line of text and add a delete button. When 1+ radio buttons are selected and the delete button is pressed, I want that line of text to go away.

The code I have right now is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    EditText editText;
    ArrayList<String> itemList;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] items={""};
        itemList=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.txtview,itemList);
        ListView listV=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listV.setAdapter(adapter);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
        Button btAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btAdd);

        btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newItem=editText.getText().toString();
                // add new item to arraylist
                itemList.add(newItem);
                // notify listview of data changed
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This ain't actually a question, you should be way more specific. And you should also start by reading some basic tutorials like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) or event taking a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)...

Comment: Please be more specific on your need.